# is P(notB|A) same as not(P(B|A))

Tags: probability, bayesian, conditional-probability, conditional

is P(notB|A) same as not(P(B|A))  if not then what is the difference  between them? this is taken from bayes question.

Comment: Where did you see the second notation? It seems very odd.

Comment: What do you or Mr Bayes believe is the meaning of `not(P(B|A))`? It is true that $$P(B^c\mid A) = 1 - P(B \mid A)$$ but $1 - P(B \mid A)$ is generally not denoted as `not(P(B|A))`.

Comment: Because "not(P(B|A))" makes no sense, we need you to edit this post before we can attempt to answer it.

Answer (score 12):

The [negation operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation) applies to logical propositions or events, not numbers.  Consequently, the operator cannot be applied to a probability.  This means that there is no such thing as $\text{not } \mathbb{P}(B|A)$.  The rule you are looking for might be the following:

$$\mathbb{P}(\text{not } B|A) = 1-\mathbb{P}(B|A).$$

Comment: Yes, that rule is what i was looking for. thanks and excuse me for my ignorance.

Comment: No excusing necessary; this site is precisely for this kind of learning, so *a priori* ignorance of correct approaches is common.